# batch file - unable to stop command

Tags: android, shell, batch-file

I created a little batch file that allows me to do some useful things on android using ADB.

To record a video from adb, the command is the following:

> adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/ScreenRecords/%screenName%.mp4

this works fine if i type it in the console everytime, but in my little script, i ahve a menu and other things that for some reasons doesn't let this command to work properly.

This is the code i have so far in my script:

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
cd C:\Android\adk\sdk\platform-tools
adb devices
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ************************************
ECHO Select what to do next:
ECHO ************************************
ECHO.
ECHO  1  - Check devices status
ECHO  X  - Close
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P M=Select the action number then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO SCREENRECORDING
IF %M%==X GOTO EOF
:SCREENRECORDING
ECHO.
SET /P screenRecordName=Type the name for the video to be recorded: 
ECHO ** Recording in progress. To close the recording process, please press CTRL+C **
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/ScreenRecords/%screenRecordName%.mp4
GOTO MENU
```

It is semplified to shows only this issue.

Now, i think that the problem is that to stop recording from adb, you need to press **CTRL+C**.

When i press CTRL+C, this appears:

> ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?

and when i press Y, it closes the all window, while if i press N, the screen record is not caputred.

Is there a way to press CTRL+C without let `^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?`

appearing and then go back to the main menu?

Sorry but i'm new to batch programming.

Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/498798)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the adb job with

```
start /wait "screencapture running" adb shell ....
```

This will open another console window, which you can stop with `ctrl-c`, while the parent script waits.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. i tried, the new window opens, but when i click ctrl + c it closed the new one but still display terminate on the parent one.

Comment: Did you first put the focus on the new window?

Comment: yes, new window closing, parent one displays terminate message